# Rails Model Association 1 model belongs to 2 models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 3 models

1. User
2. Bucket
3. Bookmarks

A user can have many bookmarks and many buckets.
Buckets belong to a user, and can have many bookmarks.
Bookmarks belong to a user and to a bucket.

Is the relationship of a user having many bookmarks, and bookmarks belonging to a user redundant if all bookmarks have to belong to a bucket.

Also the bookmark creation form looks like this

- Name
- URL
- Bucket (the bucket that the bookmark is going to belong to)

How should I go about writing the form and controller logic.

Thank You

Comment: you should grab a paper and a pencil first. Then, generate 3 scaffolds..thats it